# How to check payload size

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I am receiving message from Rabbit mq with byte[] from source application.  I want to check the size of the payload.  When I try to check #[payload.size()]  then giving  byte count as 116 or 117  but I want exactly the size of message.  Actually, I am receiving one message from Rabbit MQ so I want the 1 to set in variable or to print in log.

Comment: Is this question for Mule 3 or Mule 4?

Answer (score 0):

The message received from RabbitMQ will be the payload in Mule. If it is a byte array (ie byte[] in Java), then its size, or number of elements in the array should be `payload.length`.

It is not clear in the question why do you need the size, but it is not necessary to assign it to a variable. For logging you may want to transform it to a string or in some way. Binary payloads may not print well in the logs.

Comment: I used payload.length but it is giving  116 as size.  I need 1 to get value as I am receiving one message at a time.  And I have a choice condition after java class so I need to check the size, if size is 1 then I have to do some logic so...  Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

in mule studio you may set a break point and do check how yours payload look like before you try get it size, it may have some other bits not only expected message and that why you got size of it not 0
For example:
[image]